# O que fazer com duplicatas que só ajudam o autor?

Tags: debate, perguntas, fechamento, perguntas-duplicadas

O comum é fecharmos perguntas como duplicatas quando já há uma resposta para aquela pergunta, mesmo que não seja exatamente a mesma pergunta, mas seja exatamente a mesma resposta ou respostas que mostrem para pessoa o erro e como corrigir.

Algumas perguntas são complicadas de responder, muitas vezes porque não estão claras ou são amplas, a pessoa só joga um código e espera que depuremos para ela, o que provavelmente a faria como fora de escopo por ser um "faz pra mim".

Mas também a pergunta é ruim porque não ensina nada, só atende a necessidade da pessoa. Estritamente não é um erro de digitação ou pode ser reproduzido, mas o espírito deste motivo de fechamento é fechar algo que não ajudará outras pessoas.

Tem aparecido cada vez mais casos assim, especialmente como [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/424726/101) (só um exemplo mesmo) sobre referência nula que tem uma resposta muito boa que ensina as pessoas como resolver. Pela forma como a pergunta está feita ela parece ser suficiente, se fosse uma pergunta mais específica (raro conseguir fazer isso) talvez até merecesse uma resposta própria, mas algo tão geral, só pedindo para depurar uma resposta geral cabe mais.

O problema é que fechar como duplicata deixa a pergunta ativa ali no site para sempre e não vai ajudar nada outras pessoas sequer chegar ali porque em geral só tem o código e mensagem de erro, não tem um texto que ajude indexar melhor.

Então será que não é melhor indicar a resposta que ajudará a pessoa no comentário e fechar por outro motivo? Qual deles?

Comment: Isso é uma resposta, mas comentarei por não conseguir formular o suficiente no momento. Antes eu sempre votava como duplicata, mas não sabia que ela ficaria ativa no site; achava que sumia depois de um tempo igualmente aos outros motivos. Quando soube que funcionava assim, decidi levar em consideração o quanto a pergunta atual pode colaborar nos resultados das buscas. Se mesmo que ruim (cabe melhorias) pode ajudar nas buscas, eu voto como duplicata; se muito ruim, que possivelmente só ajuda o autor, como é o caso em questão, voto no motivo "novo", de ser acerca de programação mas sem qualidade

Comment: Estava pensando sobre isso semana passada e sinceramente, não cheguei numa resposta conclusiva, que fosse satisfatória para este problema. Mas creio que mesmo se a pergunta estiver mal formulada, mas o título estiver bem escrito e que dê para redirecionar para outra resposta, é o caso de marcar como duplicata. Mas quando a pergunta e o título são ruins, é melhor fechar. É difícil criar uma regra para isso.

Comment: Eu sempre levei em consideração a indexação (se o título faz sentido pra outra pessoa procurando ou se é específico demais, se a original já cobre os termos pesquisados, etc) - A unica razão da duplicata permanecer é favorecer a busca. Se não cumpre o objetivo acaba virando ruído. Algumas coisas como .htaccess, passar dado PHP pra JS e outros assuntos recorrentes mais atrapalham do que ajudam de tanta duplicata.

Comment: Vi que as perguntas em inglês estão sendo fechadas como `marcada como pendente como não está clara o suficiente`, a razão é a mesma de não fechar como duplicatas? Que estas perguntas ficam ativas no site.

Comment: @danieltakeshi Não, é porque a pergunta não está clara, em português ou inglês, não vai adiantar a pessoa traduzir que a pergunta continuará com problema, então pra que fechar por um motivo que resolvido a pergunta continuará fechada e agora por motivo diferente? É fechado pelo pior motivo. No passado eu achava mais importante porque isso orientava melhor a pessoa e podia ajudar salvar a pergunta, mas ultimamente as pessoas estão tão descompromissadas que não muda muito, ela só desiste em qualquer caso. Pode ver quantas vezes o autor faz um esforço genuíno de salvar a pergunta.

Comment: O que costumo fazer é editar o título para que este se adeqúe  à resposta da pergunta indicada como duplicata. [Exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/424235/2541). Haverá casos em que não será fácil, nesses,concordo consigo, o melhor é que a pergunta seja eliminada. Talvez usar "não clara"?

Comment: Relacionado em inglês [What does Stack Overflow want to be when it grows up?](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/), principalmente a parte "Over time, duplicates become vast landmine fields".