# O que fazer diante ao flood de questões?

Tags: debate

Essa última semana surgiram algumas perguntas que estão sendo repetidas com elevada frequência:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=hipster+is%3Aquestion

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=hojeSeJoga+is%3Aquestion

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=passandoPelosPares+is%3Aquestion

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=passoAPasso+is%3Aquestion

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Fiuk+is%3Aquestion

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=triplodasoma

Essas perguntas em todos os casos estão mal formuladas e deixam os usuários  menos experientes, ávidos em ganhar reputação, confusos e propensos a fornecerem respostas absurdas.

Quando recebem uma resposta adequada os autores normalmente pouco se importa em aceitar ou não e a largam em aberto.

Primeira pergunta que devo fazer é se esse tipo de flood, pelo menos eu enxergo como flood, é problema para o site?

Caso seja um problema qual seria a solução?

- Sinalizar para a moderação a remover devido a qualidade?
- Fechar como duplicada de uma pergunta equivalente que tiver a melhor resposta?
- Criar um conjunto pergunta/resposta canônica para essas perguntas para que as novas perguntas sejam sempre sinalizadas duplicadas dessas.
- Ou deixar o barco rolar e a atitude deve ser tomada pelo desenrolar de cada pergunta.

Comment: Sinaliza uma como duplicada da outra, já seria alguma coisa, mas realmente não sei o impacto disso na infra do site como um todo...

Comment: @hugocsl Isso, minha preocupação é justamente essa, dentre outras, o impacto na infra, mais precisamente na  pesquisa google. Pois se a pessoa digitar por exemplo [hojeseJoga](https://www.google.com/search?q=hojeseJoga&oq=hojeseJoga&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5j69i60l2.7121j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) vai vir uma pergunta fraca, erro grave de sintaxe e por não especificar os parâmetros de teste. Com a resposta também fraca o AR usurpa função do depurador de código e responde sob a óptica de um quandro incompleto. Quem vier de fora vai ficar mais confuso do que obter ajuda.

Comment: A solução eram todas as perguntas entrarem no site como pendentes e depois reabertas se fossem minimamente boas. Dava menos trabalho a todos.

Comment: @JorgeB. penso a mesma coisa. Se todas as perguntas entrassem fechadas iria poupar muito estres e discussão. Tem como levantar quantas vezes isso já foi pedido par SE e quais foram as respostas?

Comment: @AugustoVasques a solução não sei se já foi proposta, mas o problema já. Melhor é deixar os mods responder a isso.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/425305/101 essa encaixa como dup, não?

Comment: @Maniero essa se encaixa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=passoAPasso+is%3Aquestion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Sinalizar para a moderação a remover devido a qualidade?

Em geral não. Pode ter algum caso, mas esse motivo em si não é para sinalizar porque moderador não pode fazer nada de excepcional .Moderador pode fazer pouco além da comunidade, o problema do site hoje é que a comunidade faz pouco e moderador acaba fazendo quase tudo. Se tiver um problema específico que mereça preferencialmente uma sinalização padrão, e quem sabe uma específica que requer atenção da moderação (muita gente acha que moderador tem que cuidar de tudo, mas não) aí pode sinalizar, mas é igual qualquer outra pergunta, não porque ela faz parte desse grupo.

> Fechar como duplicada de uma pergunta equivalente que tiver a melhor resposta?

É basicamente o que está sendo discutido em [O que fazer com duplicatas que só ajudam o autor?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8066/101) e caminha para concluir que fechar como duplicata não é uma boa, só manteria uma pergunta ruim que não ajudará a outra ser melhor achada no site.

> Criar um conjunto pergunta/resposta canônica para essas perguntas para que as novas perguntas sejam sempre sinalizadas duplicadas dessas.

Poderia ser uma boa, mas não sei se resolve e pode incentivar fechar como duplicata. No fundo é dar a solução para o exercício para a pessoa copiar.

Não sei se sabem é um projeto de um grande banco que está incentivando novos programadores que está fazendo isto acontecer. O banco, mesmo sem querer, contratou uma empresa de cursos, que talvez sem querer, mas a displicência foi tão grande que dá para questionar, que seleciona as pessoas que vão participar do programa por um teste que pode ser facilmente fraudado, e o SOpt está contribuindo para a fraude ocorrer já que as pessoas que estão vindo perguntar estão demonstrando não ter capacidade nem de interpretar e escrever um texto básico, seguir instruções simples e estão dando respostas para passar no teste que eles nem entendem. Quem conseguir enganar mais tem mais chance. Este é o Brasil.

Não gosto da ideia de contribuir com isto então não gosto da ideia de fazer essas canônicas. De uma certa vai contra o espiríto do SOpt porque se a pergunta for adequada deveria ser respondida (as ruins devem ser fechadas sim, e provavelmente negativadas).

Dá para notar o descompromisso com o SOpt, programação, e até boa intenção, ainda que eles talvez acreditem que não estão fazendo nada de errado, vivemos em uma cultura de incentivar o erro, o descompromisso, a fraude, corrupção do processo, e é comum quem tenta por ordem acabar sendo taxado de errado. Tempos bem difíceis.

> Ou deixar o barco rolar e a atitude deve ser tomada pelo desenrolar de cada pergunta.

Parece o caminho, pelo menos se estiver falando que pode fechar e negativar se estiver ruim, mas acho que outras opiniões devem ser colocadas aqui.

Por outro lado manter tanta coisa assim desvirtua um pouco o SOpt, e o torna um fórum, ou pior ainda, um *help desk* fuleiro no mesmo nível do "nosso querido" Yahoo! Respostas ou vários grupos de Facebook ou WhatsApp. Mas não tem muito o que fazer, não dá para colocar porteira (até dá, começar a pergunta fechada e abrir se for boa, mas é o oposto do que a SE parece querer agora, o que me desanima bem).

Comment: para esse jeitinho brasileiro de querer ter respostas prontas desses testes de seleção é muito simples. bloquear e negativar.